# Nested Matrix Dotproduct

Tags: matrix, dot

For a given matrix `M[n]` of size $ n\times n $ I want to define the following list of matrix-expressions:

```
n=1
{Tr[M[1]]}

n=2
{Tr[M[2]]^2,Tr[M[2].M[2]]}

n=3
{Tr[M[3]]^3,Tr[M[3]]Tr[M[3].M[3]],Tr[M[3].M[3].M[3]]}
```

How could I generalize this relation for arbitrary $ n $? I tried `Nest` and `NestList`.
Thanks!

Comment: How about `n`=4?

Comment: `n=4: {{Tr[M[4]]^4,Tr[M[4]]^2Tr[M[4].M[4]],Tr[M[4]] Tr[M[4].M[4].M[4]],Tr[M[4].M[4].M[4].M[4]]}}`

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want `Tr[M[4].M[4]]^2` or `Tr[M[4]]^3 Tr[M[4]]`? What is the building scheme behind this?

Comment: I consider a sheme which contains basically a list of dotproducts `Map[Tr[#]&,{M,M.M,M.M.M,...}]`. The resulting list elements are scaled by `Tr[M]^n`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
f[k_] := Table[Tr[M @ k]^(k - i) Array[M @ k &, i, 1, Tr @ Dot @ ## &], {i, k}]

f /@ Range[5] // Column // TeXForm
```

> $\tiny\begin{array}{l}
>  \{\text{Tr}[M(1)]\} \\
>  \left\{\text{Tr}[M(2)]^2,\text{Tr}[M(2).M(2)]\right\} \\
>  \left\{\text{Tr}[M(3)]^3,\text{Tr}[M(3).M(3)] \text{Tr}[M(3)],\text{Tr}[M(3).M(3).M(3)]\right\} \\
>  \left\{\text{Tr}[M(4)]^4,\text{Tr}[M(4).M(4)] \text{Tr}[M(4)]^2,\text{Tr}[M(4).M(4).M(4)] \text{Tr}[M(4)],\text{Tr}[M(4).M(4).M(4).M(4)]\right\}
>    \\
>  \left\{\text{Tr}[M(5)]^5,\text{Tr}[M(5).M(5)] \text{Tr}[M(5)]^3,\text{Tr}[M(5).M(5).M(5)] \text{Tr}[M(5)]^2,\text{Tr}[M(5).M(5).M(5).M(5)]
>    \text{Tr}[M(5)],\text{Tr}[M(5).M(5).M(5).M(5).M(5)]\right\} \\
> \end{array}$

Comment: That's it, thank you!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, my pleasure.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann kglr's solution seems to fit your requirements, and sufficient time has elapsed without any better implementations. You might consider formally accepting his answer then! You can do so by clicking on the grey check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
listVonMat[M_] := Module[{n = Length[M], inter1, inter2},
         inter1 = TakeDrop[Table[M, n], #] & /@ Range[n - 1, 0, -1];
         inter2 = {Times @@ Tr /@ #1, Tr @ (Dot @@ #2)} & @@@ inter1;
         Times @@@ inter2
        ]
```

Maybe numerical results are easier to be checked with:

```
listVonMat[Partition[Range[#^2], #]] & /@ Range[4]
```

returns

```
{
 {1}, 
 {25, 29}, 
 {3375, 3915, 4185}, 
 {1336336, 1521296, 1613776, 1719056}
}
```

---

**Update**

To show that the scheme is indeed implemented, run, e.g., codes below

```
TakeDrop[{a, a, a, a}, #] & /@ Range[3, 0, -1]
Times @@@ ({Times @@ Tr /@ #1, Tr @ (Dot @@ #2)} & @@@ %)
```

and one gets

```
{{{a, a, a}, {a}}, {{a, a}, {a, a}}, {{a}, {a, a, a}}, {{}, {a, a, a, a}}}
{Tr[a]^4, Tr[a]^2 Tr[a.a], Tr[a] Tr[a.a.a], Tr[a.a.a.a]}
```

Comment: Thank you   for your solution

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann You're welcome. But it seems that I made things harder :(